# Convert from SQL Server to Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, t-sql, plsql, converters

I have 3 very large stored procedure I need convert from SQL Server to Oracle, is that a converter out there that anyone has tried that would work for this? I really don't want to have to do this manually if there is another option.

Answer (score 3):

Best place to start is [Oracle's SQL Developer Migration Workbench](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/migration/workbench/files/sdmwb_wp.html).  It's free.

Answer (score 2):

Please see: [Convert MS SQL script to Mysql and Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389759/convert-ms-sql-script-to-mysql-and-oracle)

Answer (score 0):

[SwissSQL](http://www.swissql.com/products/sqlserver-to-oracle/sql-server-to-oracle.html) have a free trial version you could try.